# Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource with the RabbitMQ.Client.dll exception

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, nuget, runtime-error, assembly-loading

Why may I be getting the following error and how could I fix it?

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in RabbitMQ.Client.dll
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource, Version=1.1.28.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

**UPDATE**

After the comment in the comments sections below I am trying to find the **Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource** in **Visual Studio 2019**. I am using the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + T` for this, but still can not find the file. Where could the file be placed?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOoWh.png)

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: Can you check the Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource dependency version that you have in your project structure. The error says version 1.1.28.0 is what RabbitMQ.Client.dll is after.

Comment: @Nair, how can I do that?

Comment: @hellouworld, You can right click on the Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource dll and view the properties, which will list details about dll including the version number. Alternately, you can view the same from the project file if you were to open in any editor.

Comment: @Nair, I updated my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not alone - this is a [known issue](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/420) with the RabbitMQ .NET client, which has  also been discussed on the [rabbitmq-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rabbitmq-users/vqXM0B0m48U/ezPazFBpAwAJ).

The fix will ship with the next major release (v6) of the client. Until then, a workaround for may be to downgrade the nuget package

Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.Redist

to the specific version 1.1.28.0. (This was suggested in the [discussion](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/420#issuecomment-404938726) of the issue.) How to downgrade is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio) - observe that in the second step, you need to choose the specific version mentioned above, instead of the latest version.

My team has recently hit the same issue, and we're testing this workaround at the moment.

**UPDATE (2020-02-03):** We've successfully tested the workaround; the app no longer crashes.

And I may add a short explanation of Nair's comment. After installing the suitable old version of the nuget package, you can verify in the Solution Explorer that you really have version 1.1.28.0, by expanding the references of your project and look at the properties of your reference:

[image: The Properties Window for Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.Redist DLL in the Solution Explorer]

The screenshot shows the old version 1.1.28.0, as desired. Of course you can look up the version of the referenced DLL at any time in this way.

**UPDATE (2020/07/13):** version 6 of the rabbitmq .NET client has been released. In our team, we still cannot update because we need to wait for the correspondig version 6 of the NServiceBus wrapper, but that will be [released as well within the next few weeks](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.RabbitMQ/issues/627).

Comment: One another option (which worked for me) is to avoid the RabbitMQ errors whatsoever. :)

Comment: A dangerous option :-) Remember what Gordon Letwin once said: "one in a million is next tuesday": https://web.archive.org/web/20120124204400/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/03/30/104165.aspx